# V11.1: Effective methods to use paid functions economically

Tags: evaluation, paid-functions

In the newly released version 11.1, *Mathematica* introduces three new functions: [WebSearch](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WebSearch.html), [WebImageSearch](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WebImageSearch.html) and [TextTranslation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TextTranslation.html) that requires [Service Credits](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ServiceCreditsAvailable.html). While I haven't found much information about it, there are several characteristics I notice.

- It is a separated service from Cloud Credit, and they do not share credits. (It can be proved by evaluating `$ServiceCreditsAvailable` and `$CloudCreditsAvailable`)
- Functions require Service Credits consumes a certain amount of credits on each evaluation **locally**(a fundamental difference with cloud credits).
- `WebSearch` and `WebImageSearch` consume approximately 3 credits per run, while `TextTranslation` consumes 1 credit per run (at least).
- These functions do not cache the content, even if the queries are the same. (screenshot below)

[image]

When writing scripts with such functions, sometimes a bug could cause evaluating expression repeatedly unintentionally. With this possibility, service credits can be used up quickly without notice. With the trend of Wolfram Language integrating more highly automated informational functions with external services, I expect to see more functions of this kind in the future.

So I think having some overall control writing/executing scripts with paid functions are necessary. I thought of function `Once` to cache the result, in case there are identical calls, credits will be saved. The code illustrating this idea looks like this:

```
saveMoney[fun_] := 
 Module[{code = DownValues[fun]}, 
  DownValues[fun] = 
   Replace[code, {(h : (WebSearch | WebImageSearch | 
           TextTranslation))[a___] :> Once[h[a]]}, Infinity]]
```

However, it requires manually applying this function on each symbol defined. And this function has no control when the content string for calls are different. It is also possible to limit the number of times those functions can execute during an evaluation, but I have not tried to implement this yet.

What are some more effective methods(code) to control the unintended usages of those functions?

Comment: This has been done many times before in *Mathematica* for a variety of purposes. [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1140/731) could probably be adapted for example.

Comment: I sincerely hope this is a bug.  Surely a *local call* should not be charged *service* rates.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It seems that these function don't have caching by default. So in default cases, all calls will be sent to Wolfram's server thus charge Service Credits. :(

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think Wolfram will be moving more services to the cloud in the future:(

Comment: Violence is inappropriate.

Answer (score 15):

Run the following code before you start your work or directly add this piece into `init.m` would solve the problem (at least for a while).

```
Options@TextTranslation;
Function[{func},
   Once[
    Module[{dv},
     dv = DownValues@func;
     Unprotect@func;

     DownValues[func] = {};
     AppendTo[Options[func], SaveMoney -> True];
     func[content___, opts : OptionsPattern[func]] := 
      If[TrueQ[OptionValue@SaveMoney], Once, Identity][
       ReleaseHold[((# -> OptionValue@# & /@ 
             Options[func][[;; -2, 1]]) /. {optseq__} :> 
            Hold[func[content, optseq]]) /. dv]];

     Protect[func, SaveMoney];
     ]
    ]
   ] /@ {WebSearch, WebImageSearch, TextTranslation};
```

[image: Effect Image]

Or a slightly enhanced version with total Service Credit usage monitoring:

```
Options@TextTranslation;
$MaxSCUsage = 2(*Adjust the Maximum Service Credit Allowed to use Here!!!*);
$InitSC = $ServiceCreditsAvailable;
Function[{func},
   Once[
    Module[{dv},
     dv = DownValues@func;
     Unprotect@func;

     DownValues[func] = {};
     AppendTo[Options[func], SaveMoney -> True];
     func[content___, opts : OptionsPattern[func]] := 
      With[{sc = $ServiceCreditsAvailable}, 
       If[$InitSC - sc >= $MaxSCUsage, 
        Print["You've used " <> ToString[$InitSC - sc] <> 
          " Service Credits in this Session!!!\nONLY " <> 
          ToString[sc] <> 
          " Service Credits Left!!!\nYOUR WALLET is BLEEDING!!!!!!!!!"];
        Abort[],
        If[TrueQ[OptionValue@SaveMoney], Once, Identity][
         ReleaseHold[((# -> OptionValue@# & /@ 
               Options[func][[;; -2, 1]]) /. {optseq__} :> 
              Hold[func[content, optseq]]) /. dv]]]];

     Protect[func, SaveMoney];
     ]
    ]
   ] /@ {WebSearch, WebImageSearch, TextTranslation};
```

[image: With SC Monitoring]

Let me explain a bit:

- For usage, one can use the extra option `SaveMoney` with default value `True` to enable and disable this feature.
- For realization, I used `Once` to ensure identical `TextTranslation` would only evaluate once. In the previous result, we can see that duplicative evaluation of `TextTranslation` would cost no Service Credits and the response is quite sharp(Try it yourself~).(Goal Achieved!)

Hope this feature can really save some precious Service Credits ~ :P

---

**Note 1:** The previous code could be easily used in almost any occasion where one need to aviod duplicative evaluation(Except those extremely rare cases with both `Protected` and `Locked` enabled). Also, one can add the code without any modification to other codes as it add this feature without adding a new function.

**Note 2:** One can use the following function instead of using the internal `TextTranslation`(But as it's in some way violating terms of service as xtian777x said, I don't recommend extensive usage). Seriously, its faster and gives similar quality result at least when using google translation.

Now this piece of code aims to translate Chinese to English, a slight upgration of this code can enable multiple language to language translation:

```
MyTextTranslation[chn_] := 
 StringCases[
   Quiet@URLRead[
     "https://translate.google.com/m?hl=zh-CN&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&ie=UTF-8&\
prev=_m&q=" <> chn, "Body", FollowRedirects -> True, 
     CharacterEncoding -> None], 
   "<div dir=\"ltr\" class=\"t0\">" ~~ Shortest[c__] ~~ "</div>" :> 
    c][[1]]
```

(Special Note for Chinese users, use .cn instead of .com)

The result is of the same quality as `TextTranslate`'s solution:

[image: sample translation result]

Comment: The answer you got is very excited.

Comment: I won't strongly suggest using the function you wrote (MyTextTranslation) because you'll probably get blocked by Google since they don't have a free quota (https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq) and you'll probably be violating their terms of service.

Comment: @xtian777x The fact is I'm trying to visit Google translate site and fetch and proceed the HTMl I get instead of connecting to Google translate API. Thus probably it won't be blocked. Also, by using Google translate in this way I suppose I'm not violating the Google translate website's terms of service?

Comment: @xtian777x Also, you can see that the result given is different, which I strongly suspect Google is providing a better translation service for paid API users.

Comment: @Wjx I'm just guessing with some sort of confidence about the terms since they don't have a free API and I'm sure they want to make money and avoid overuse of the free web based version. If you don't use it too much they probably won't notice, but, even if used manually, they will block you after so many translations. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339190/scraping-html-from-google-translate

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. Surely one should use API when one can if screen scrapping is violating service terms, I don't know much about that, thanks!